# Grafana singlestat dashboard based on previous average number

Tags: dashboard, grafana, prometheus

i have a dashboard that shows a sum of requests/sec with from a  windows performance monitor collected by prometheus.
sum(Total_Query_Received_persec)

I would like to see any issues right away if those request/sec drop ( which will indicate an issue) 
So the singlestat panel could change color if the number of request/sec is 50% less than the same number collected 10 minutes ago (for example), change panel coloring to yellow and if the number is 80% less than 10 minutes ago change color to Red.
I know that you can configure this based on thresholds, but not sure if there is a way to query that info in the metric.

Is this possible at all?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar enough to grafana to provide all the details of handling the color change scenarios with that tool, but within prometheus the query you are interested in can likely be handled with the [irate operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#irate()). It's only recommended for working with 'fast moving' counters, and the documentation mentions that you should track the irate() internal to a sum() to keep from hiding the volatility from the function.

You might also get perfectly acceptable performance and results from aggregating the detail with rate directly, such as `rate(total_query_received_persec)[10m]`